# Scrumboard for Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, agile, scrum

We're currently using Visual Studio 2015 Community and Team Foundation Server 2010.

Are there any open-source C# projects that connect to TFS and display the workitems as a scrumboard?

Comment: TFS 2010 is no longer being actively supported by Microsoft. If you upgrade to TFS 2015 you get a great scrum board built into the product.

Comment: @jessehouwing Does an in-place upgrade to TFS 2015 include the scrum board which can be accessed from VS 2015 Community?

Comment: It's a web-based scrum board, so it's accessible even without VS 2015 Community.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I remember looking for one back when TFS2010 was the current version and could find none that worked well.

As jessehouwing mentioned, if possible, upgrade to TFS 2015 (or better yet, [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/), which is TFS in the cloud) to get a really useful Scrum board and Kanban board.